# Can't create Angular app in terminal NG New MacOS

Tags: angular, macos, terminal

When I try to create an Angular app in the terminal using `ng new my-project-name` I get `zsh: command not found: ng`.

What I've tried:

- Installing Node
- Installing XCode
- Installing Homebrew
- Running `npm install -g @angular/cli`
- Running `npm link @angular/cli`

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself (thanks guys). The solution was to put sudo in front of the  npm install -g @angular/cli